# Can I use the minimum value of a column created with AS?

Tags: sql, count, min

In my task I needed to create a new column that shows how many singers are in some specific bands.
So far I did this in the SELECT section:

```
SELECT bands.name, count(\*) AS singernumber
FROM....
```

So my quiestion is how can I reduce the shown datas to only the ones with the biggest value.
Can I use MIN refered to the "singernumber" column?

```
SELECT bands.name, count(\*) AS singernumber
FROM bands, artists
WHERE bands.id=artists.id
AND artists.role LIKE "*singer*"
GROUP BY bands.name, bands.id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You canuse `HAVING` to exluse like in the follwoing alm that more than two singers.

but you should switch to JOIN, comma separated are not used anymore

```
SELECT bands.name, count(*) AS singernumber 
FROM bands INNER JOIN artists 
ON bands.id=artists.id 
WHERE artists.role LIKE "*singer*" 
GROUP BY bands.name, bands.id
HAVING COUNT)(*) > 2;
```